# Identifying PCB based Connectors

Tags: pcb, identification, connector, terminal

I am trying to identify the type/class of connectors that similar to PCB straight type connectors that you see in RAM modules, PCIe Cards.

I have this custom board for which I am trying to identify the female and male connectors and the different types of pitches they come for. Is there something that is specific for dual side connectors as well?

[image: Pitch of 0.6 mm]

Comment: I think they are called edge connectors, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_connector

Comment: Are you answering the question? If not, you might want to just edit your question to add more information. As it is we will assume since you posted an answer you have answered the question yourself and you don't need help from the rest of us.

Comment: no dimensions? why? https://suddendocs.samtec.com/literature/samtec_edge_card_application_design_guide.pdf

Comment: Why not measure with calipers and try to match up with off the shelf card edge connectors?

Comment: I've converted your answer into a question. Somebody may be able to provide a less generic answer.